# Does $u_h \rightharpoonup u$ in $*w-W^{1,\infty}$ imply $(u_h)$ equi lipschitz?

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence, lipschitz-functions

I was wondering if the following fact is true:

I consider a sequence $(u_h)\subset W^{1, \infty}(U, \mathbb{R}^N)$, with $U$ open bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $$u_h \rightharpoonup u$$ $*w-W^{1,\infty}$ (the * weak convergence).

Can I say that this $(u_h)$ is equi-lipschitz, i.e $\exists$ $M$ such that $|u_h(x)-u_h(y)\leq M|x-y|$ for every $x,y\in\Omega$ and for every index $h$?

Can I use perhaps the fact that this sequence is bounded in $W^{1,\infty}$?

I would like to know if this fact is true without any other assumption on $\Omega$.

I think that the answer is no, because if $\Omega $ is general, I cannot say that a function in $W^{1,\infty}$ is also Lipschitz. Am I right?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Of course you have to say "almost everywhere".  If you assume $U$ has $C^1$ boundary, then you get this directly from the $W^{1,\infty}$ boundedness and [Morrey's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Morrey.27s_inequality), which says the Lipschitz constant is controlled by the $W^{1,\infty}$ norm.  Without assuming a smooth boundary, I'd worry.

Comment: Oh, for an easy counterexample if you drop $C^1$ boundary, take $U$ to be a disk with a slit.  Indeed, finding a single $W^{1,\infty}$ function $u$ which is not Lipschitz is sufficient; then you can just let $u_h = u$ for every $h$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you for your help!